# Compare list magento in a static block

Tags: magento, compare

How can i add the sidebar from compare list in magento in a static block? This doesnt work

```
{{block type="catalog/product_compare" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change block type to this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"}}
```